# MATLAB: how to save time when using double loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm using MATLAB to check whether scatter intersects with buildings,
and I used double loop, and I know it costs a lot of time.

But I found less exact and clear answer on the Internet.

Could anyone help me to optimize it?

Note: `intersectionCheck` is the method I wrote myself

```
for i=1:originalScatterNumber
    for k=1:clusterNumber
        flag(i,k) = intersectionCheck(UE, ...
            [scatter(i,1),scatter(i,2),scatter(i,3)], ...
            ClusterCoordinate(k,1),ClusterCoordinate(k,2), ...
            buildingLength(k),buildingWidth(k),clusterBoundaryInfo(k,5));
    end
    if sum(flag(i,:) == 1) == clusterNumber
        scatterWhetherIntersect(i) = 1;
    else
        scatterWhetherIntersect(i) = 0;
    end
end
```

Comment: You can change the outer `for` loop by a `parfor`, if this function is very slow, than this might make it faster. But if it needs to run multiple times, parfor has some big communication overhead,so it might not help. Also you need the parallel processing toolbox to use this.

Comment: Your best bet is to vectorize `intersectionCheck` itself so you can pass all data at once.

Comment: It might speed up a little bit if you use `for 1 = N:-1:1` instead of `for i = 1:N`. The reverse order makes sure MATLAB preallocates variables like `flag` and `scatterWhetherIntersect` when they are set for the first time. Otherwise preallocate them before the `for`-loops. Vectorising `intersectionCheck` is the best thing you can do. Also, you can use the MATLAB Profiler with the button at the top called ‘Run and Time’ or alternatively use `profile on, <run your code here>, profile off, profile viewer`. Then investigate which commands in your code require a lot of time and could be enhanced.